# SOAP In c++ CGI

Tags: c++, apache, web-services, soap, cgi

I am doing a web project using multiple server.
A Bank Account Holder can have accounts in multiple bank. I setup that Every bank has have their own server. Bank A contains their data in Bank A server. 
Bank B contains their data in Bank B server and so on. When an Account Holder login, I will check his user authentication in a Web server and will find in Which bank he has the account. Once I find the bank, I need to send a request to a appropriate bank server for his account details. Bank Server need to run my query and handover the data to Web server. Then Web server collects the data from the bank server and returns the data to client browser.

> Client -> Web Server(Authentication + Find Bank) -> Bank Server
>
> Bank Server -> Web Server -> Client
>
> or
>
> Bank Server -> Client

I am using CGI in c++. I just investigated that How can I do this task? I found that I can do this By SOAP or RESTful. But I didn't know how to communicate among the Bank Servers using c++. Till and now my working method is,

> Client Browser -> Cgi call -> Run cgi which is compiled by C++.
>
> CGI ( Text Format: Content-type:text/plain  or Content-type:text/HTML)
>   -> Client Browser.

Now I need,

> Request: Client Browser -> Web Server CGI -> Bank Server CGI
>
> Response: Bank Server CGI  -> Web Server CGI -> Client Browser.

How can I do this using SOAP or RESTful? Is there any Sample Code or Tutorial Available?

Comment: This is quite a generic question. What web server are you using? Why are you using CGI? Are you spawning your own http listeners?

Comment: Apache Web Server. Why are you using CGI ? Its just a try.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well you should read more about SOAP and REST before you make your decision. REST is just a design principle, SOAP is a mechanism for call remote procedures via web technology. Both could work with CGI but SOAP in particular is probably overkill.

CGI is a script/exe that you call from your server to generate an output, but it will spawn a process every time. The process returns an output and dies, taking any memory with it. They are normally used for generating output that is not reliant on any state.

In that case you would need some kind of central process that acts as a shared memory for the CGI processes. That could be a DB that you access via the CGI calls, or another process that you know how to "call" (e.g. using a messaging service).

Normally I would use an in-built extension mechanism (in-built to the server) to handle this. Most often for items of this type I would use tomcat and a Java Rest service. I have also used gSoap hosted as its own service.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to study to complete my task using gSoap?

Comment: Google is your friend for that Dwayne. It's not a fantasticallly easy to use library IMO, and the license is not free for commercial use. You can also check our the cpprestsdk from Microsoft. It is free and it looks decent.